# CMake + MinGW + Clang on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, clang, mingw

I would like to compile an application with using Clang 4.0, CMake 3.8.1, MinGW x86_64 6.3.0. I've tried:

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ ..\code
```

but a compilation of a test program failed because of passing Visual Studio's compiler arguments. I'd like to not use Visual Studio at all. 
Output:

```
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 4.0.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 4.0.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:51 (message):
The C compiler "C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.
clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: '/nologo'
clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: '/DWIN32'
clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: '/D_WINDOWS'
```

I also tried:

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="C:/Program Files/LLVM/msbuild-bin/cl.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="C:/Program Files/LLVM/msbuild-bin/cl.exe" -DCMAKE_LINKER="C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/lld-link.exe" ..\code
```

and it also failed while compilation a test program:

```
 C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\bin\lld-link.exe /nologo
 @CMakeFiles\cmTC_afe59.dir\objects1.rsp /out:cmTC_afe59.exe
 /implib:cmTC_afe59.lib
 /pdb:C:\...........\_build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_afe59.pdb
 /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /pdbtype:sept /INCREMENTAL:YES
 /subsystem:console kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib
 comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib
 odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib

 error: could not open /pdbtype:sept: no such file or directory
```

Is it possible to force Clang with MinGw on Windows 10?

Comment: I dont know who you are, or what you saw but i have this _exact_ problem, exact down to the directory names... If either of us finds the solution, tell the other

Comment: I'm getting the same error with the ""objects1.rsp" line having an at symbol (@) in front of it. I'm on a Windows 10 machine with CMake 3.12.1 with the NMake JOM generator

Comment: I run into `lld-link.exe: error: could not open kernel32.lib: no such file or directory`, because CMake or something puts kernel32.lib etc on the link line. I tried this using LLVM/clang 7.0

Answer (score 0):

Those are MSVC parameters. I have come across several libraries that assume these work when checking for `IF(WIN32)` in `CMakeLists.txt`, while it should be `IF(MSVC)`.

There is a MinGW-w64 available with both GCC and LLVM/CLang at http://winlibs.com/ but as it's not MSVC those parameters still need to be avoided, so I recommend you fix `CMakeLists.txt` and run cmake again.